# $M(\frac{1}{f})=M(f)^{-1}$

Tags: calculus

Given any function f of one variable, infinitely differentiable, define 
$$M(f)=\begin{bmatrix}f & 0 & 0\\f' & f & 0\\f'' & 2f' & f \end{bmatrix}$$

I have to verify that $M(\frac{1}{f})=M(f)^{-1}$. My first thought was to consider Cayley-Hamilton Theorem to express $M(f)^{-1}$ as a polynomial and then use the fact that $M(P(f))=P(M(f))$, where $P$ is any polynomial, but I got stucked.

Comment: I think you can just proceed directly in this case: multiply $M(f)M(1/f)$ and conclude that you get $I$.

Comment: @ian thank you! I got it!